# c++ Multiple Inheritance ambiguity, Inheriting from two classes which contain the same names for member data

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I have the problem that I am trying to access member data from two parent classes which has the same name ObjectArray. ObjectArray is a vector of either the Subcircuit class or the component class. I essentialy want to perform the same function on them twice "getImpedence".

```
virtual complex<double> getImpedence(){
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ObjectArray.size(); i++){
        ObjectImpedence += ObjectArray[i].getImpedence();
    }
    return ObjectImpedence;
};
```

Which is a recursive function in the base class SetOfElectricalComponents which moves down the hierarchy so that once ObjectArray[i] Is a component it returns a complex double.

A working solution without multiple inheritance removing constructors is to overide the "getImpedence" function

```
class MainCircuit :public SetOfElectricalComponents<SubCircuit> {
protected:
    vector<Component> ExtraComponentsArray;
public:

// function that returns Impedence for MainCircuit
complex<double> getImpedence(){

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ObjectArray.size(); i++){
        ObjectImpedence += ObjectArray[i].getImpedence();
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ExtraComponentsArray.size(); i++){
        ObjectImpedence += ExtraComponentsArray[i].getImpedence();
    }
    return ObjectImpedence;
}

void addExtra(Component item){ cout << "here" << endl; ExtraComponentsArray.push_back(item); };
};
```

But Using Multiple Inheritance something like

```
class MainCircuit :public SetOfElectricalComponents<SubCircuit>,SetOfElectricalComponents<Component> {
protected:
    vector<Component> ExtraComponentsArray;
public:

// function that returns Impedence for MainCircuit
complex<double> getImpedence(){} // Do this for Both Object Arrays?

void addExtra(Component item){ cout << "here" << endl; ExtraComponentsArray.push_back(item); };
};
```

Is where I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Why don't you just use two member variables instead of two base classes?

Comment: In the same way as ExtraComponentsArray? Because I want the end user to be able to write .add(some component or higher class)  If I use two variables I don't think I would be able to do it as generally.

Comment: You can select members of a specific base class by qualifying the names, like `Base1::ObjectArray` and `Base2::ObjectArray`. And possibly first `using Base1 = very_long_class_name;`

Comment: I agree with Christian, this looks like a "has a" rather than an "is a" relationship. For "has a" you would use composition. You don't gain any generality using multiple inheritance because you would have to name both base classes (vs. naming both member variables).

Comment: Thanks :: Is what i'm looking for, and yes I think it is a has a i'll think about that

Comment: Just to clarify: the two `ObjectArray`s contain different objects?

Comment: Yes both vectors but vectors of different derived classes , of the same base class template. One is like a vector that contains multiple the other (which is also a vector). Rewriting using has a fixed things.